# Solving implicitly a trigonometric equation

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry, implicit

I am trying to solve this equation with respect to `L`:

```
L== ((9.81*T^2)/(2*Pi)) Tan[2Pi*d/L]
```

Since you have the unknown `L` on both sides you need to solve it implicitly. I tried this way

```
Solve [L == ((9.81*T^2)/(2*Pi)) Tan[2*Pi/L*d], L]
```

However, it is not working and I am thus at a lost. The idea would be to be able to easily change the values of `T` and `d` but right now I am happy even if the values are hardcoded in.

Comment: Try `FindRoot`.  But need to first set some numerical values for `T` and `d`. Like this `eq = L == ((981/100*T^2)/(2*Pi))* Tan[2 Pi*d/L];
eq = eq /. {d -> 2, T -> 3};
FindRoot[eq, {L, .2}]`  gives `{L -> 0.199955}`. Not likely there is analytical solution for this.

Comment: I guess you are expecting infinite number of solutions in the interval $[0,1]$? See this `LogLinearPlot[{L,Tan[1/L]},{L,0.02,5}]`.

Answer (score 3):

Solutions of such equations are in general transcendental numbers and they cannot be expressed in terms of radicals or elementary functions. Nonetheless *Mathematica* can represent such solutions in the form of the `Root` objects, i.e. they are exact solutions which can be transformed symbolically and approximated numerically with arbitrary precision.

Since `Tan` is a periodic function there are infinitely many solutions and so we have to restrict appropriately the range of the `L` variable to find a finite number of solutions  with e.g. `Reduce` or `Solve`.  There are finite nubers of solutions in compact ranges (closed and bounded) if `0` does not belong to such ranges, in other words in any neighbourhood of `0` there are infinitely many solutions.
Moreover we have to prescribe values to symbols `d` and `T` since in our case the system could not find any solutions.
A convenient way of of prescibing values is  by exploiting `With`, e.g. between `1/6` and `1/4` there are four solutions:

```
With[{d = 1, T = 1/2, g = 981/100}, 
      SolveValues[L == ((g T^2)/(2 Pi)) Tan[2 Pi/L*d] && 1/6 < L < 1/4, L]]
```

> ```
> {Root[{800 Pi # - 981 Tan[2 Pi/#]& , 
>         0.17957748281348739000707018642741166076`20.300821707508064}], 
>  Root[{800 Pi # - 981 Tan[2 Pi/#]& , 
>         0.19706718722743780186902652559969972253`20.301033843594166}], 
>  Root[{800 Pi # - 981 Tan[2 Pi/#]& , 
>         0.2182855980879414773470867114489761944`20.560936998685662}], 
>  Root[{800 Pi # - 981 Tan[2 Pi/#]& , 
>         0.24455382334624683616102511276986516091`20.587965068681747}]}
> ```

To make a clear plot we restrict the graph `Tan[c/L]` with `ConditionalExpression`:

```
With[{d = 1, T = 1/2, g = 981/100}, 
  Plot[{ConditionalExpression[((g T^2)/(2 Pi)) Tan[2 Pi/L*d], 8/100 < L], L},
       {L, 0, 1/4}, PlotRange -> 2/3, Axes -> {0, 0}, Evaluated -> True, 
       ImageSize -> Large
       Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{#, #}] & /@ sol}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, it's unlikely there's an analytical solution, so if you have numerical values for everything else then `FindRoot` is one approach.

Another way is to use fixed point iteration, but you need to change the equation a bit as the current $L_{n+1} \leftarrow \tan(b/L_n)/a$ form is too unstable and chaotic. Instead use $L_{n+1}\leftarrow b/\arctan(a L_n)$

```
g = 9.81; T = 3; d = 2; a = (2 Pi)/(g T^2); b = 2 d Pi;
eqn = a L == Tan[b/L];
result = FixedPoint[b/ArcTan[a #] &, .1, 10000]; Print@result;
(* 15.2242 *)
(* get the error and check it's very low *)
eqn /. {Equal -> Subtract, L -> result}
```

You could also solve as a minimization of the square difference of lhs and rhs of the equation:

```
{err,sol}=NMinimize[{(a L-Tan[b/L])^2,L>0.01},L,Method->"RandomSearch"]
eqn /. sol
```

Comment: Solutions analytically depend on parameters, i.e. $L=L(d, T,g)$ are analytical functions of their arguments and writing "there is no analytical solution" makes a confusion.

Comment: @Artes I wrote _"it's unlikely there's an analytical solution"_ so there's nothing wrong with that statement. Analytic has multiple meanings beyond just the complex analysis sense, and is related to closed forms - see 'analytic expression'.

Comment: Right, my comment doesn't intend to point out any mistakes but rather to avoid using ambiguous statement. I guess this might be helpful at least for newcomers not increasing unnecessary noise.

Answer (score 1):

The expectations "it's unlikely there's an analytical solution" in this case are  incorrect. `Dimensional analysis` show a way to transform the equation in a twodimensional parameterspace.

Transformation of the parameterspace

```
eq = L == ((9.81*T^2)/(2*Pi)) Tan[2 Pi*d/L] /. {L -> 2 Pi d/x, T -> Sqrt[d] /y} // FullSimplify[#, d > 0] &
```

gives a twodimensional  equation in the new parameters `x==2 Pi d/L, y==Sqrt[d]/T`

which is visualized  with

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[eq ], {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 5},FrameLabel -> {2 Pi d/L, Sqrt[d]/T}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

That's the analytical solution you asked for!

Comment: Just curious, what do you understand under the term "analytical solution"?

Comment: @yarchik Perhaps "parametric relationship" is a better description?

Comment: Perhaps :), let's leave it to math experts. I first thought, you are talking about analyticity in the holomorphic function sense. Thanks for clarifying it.